# View returned from function does not update on state change

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, antd

I'am using ant design components in react, Where I have used the steps component which uses the views returned from an array in which I have used functions to return the view, However the views are rendered correctly for the first time but when the state changes the views are not updated accordingly, Also if I use input elements I can't type into those input elements, please help

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Steps, Button, message, Form, Icon, Input } from "antd";
const { Step } = Steps;

class Register extends Component {
  state = {
    current: 0,
    getFieldDecorator: this.props.form.getFieldDecorator,
    email: "",
    username: "",
    password: "",
    password2: "",
    imageSelected: false,
    imageSource: null
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      imageSource: URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  firstStepContent = (
    <Form className="firstPage" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <Form.Item>
        {this.state.getFieldDecorator("email", {
          rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please enter an email" }]
        })(
          <Input
            prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />}
            placeholder="Enter email"
            name="email"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            type="email"
          />
        )}
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
        {this.state.getFieldDecorator("username", {
          rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please enter a username " }]
        })(
          <Input
            prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />}
            placeholder="Enter username "
            name="username"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            type="text"
          />
        )}
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
        {this.state.getFieldDecorator("password", {
          rules: [{ required: true, message: "Please enter a password " }]
        })(
          <Input.Password
            prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />}
            placeholder="Enter password"
            name="password"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            type="password"
          />
        )}
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item>
        {this.state.getFieldDecorator("password2", {
          rules: [
            { required: true, message: "Please enter confirmation password" }
          ]
        })(
          <Input.Password
            prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />}
            placeholder="Confirm password"
            name="password2"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        )}
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );

  uploadButton = (
    <div>
      <Icon type="plus" />
      <div className="ant-upload-text">Select a profile photo</div>
    </div>
  );

  secondStepContent = (
    <div className="imageUpload">
      <div className="imageBox">
        {this.state.imageSource && <img src={this.state.imageSource} />}
        <input
          className="fileSelect"
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          onChange={this.onChange}
          style={{ opacity: "0" }}
        />
        <div className="imageMessage">
          <Icon type="plus" />

          <p>Select an profile image</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  thirdStepContent = <div />;

  steps = [
    {
      title: "Login Credentials",
      content: this.firstStepContent
    },
    {
      title: "Profile Image",
      content: this.secondStepContent
    },
    {
      title: "Bio",
      content: this.thirdStepContent
    }
  ];

  next = () => {
    this.setState({
      current: this.state.current + 1
    });
  };

  prev = () => {
    this.setState({
      current: this.state.current - 1
    });
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { current } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="registerComponent">
        <Steps current={current}>
          {this.steps.map(item => (
            <Step key={item.title} title={item.title} />
          ))}
        </Steps>
        <div className="steps-content">{this.steps[current].content}</div>
        <div className="steps-action">
          {current < this.steps.length - 1 && (
            <Button type="primary" onClick={() => this.next()}>
              Next
            </Button>
          )}
          {current === this.steps.length - 1 && (
            <Button
              type="primary"
              onClick={() => message.success("Processing complete!")}
            >
              Done
            </Button>
          )}
          {current > 0 && (
            <Button style={{ marginLeft: 8 }} onClick={() => this.prev()}>
              Previous
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedRegisterForm = Form.create({ name: "register" })(Register);

export default WrappedRegisterForm;
```

Comment: Hi Rohan, can you provide a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/) so way may debug properly? also, can you tell what exactly the changes in the `state` that stops the component from rendering properly?

Comment: Sure( https://codesandbox.io/embed/prod-paper-spzhu ), if the image source is selected it should render the img tag, And in firststepcontent I can't type into the text fields

Comment: I have been trying both `getValueFromEvent` and `getValueFromEvent` option from `antd`, I wan't able to figure out, I'll be back to work on this afternoon this day if it wasn't  solved yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to answer the input question.

1. Unable to type into input element

   It's because JSX that `step` renders was assign to `firstStepContent` directly.
   in the other word, `firstStepContent = (JSX)` made `firstStepContent` unable to change in every react lifecycle.

   To fix it, just change it into function:`firstStepContent =()=> (JSX)` , 
   and call it in render phase: 
   `<div className="steps-content">{this.steps[current].content()}</div>`

   I forked your codesandbox, and put `original firstStepContent` above `function` one.

   They print the component state as JSON string of either JSX, so you can observed the difference:
   https://fkbft.codesandbox.io/